Ubuntu "Splash screen"?
I got a laptop with Ubuntu less than a year ago and decided to switch from gnome to KDE Plasma. Now every time I exit a full screen application or make changes in the settings I see this image and I'm wondering if there's a way to make it disappear.
Here's a video of what happens
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/793153738452762624/1224372980272857179/IMG_3381.mov?ex=661d4132&is=660acc32&hm=1aa0aaca6fc0d4040515392fe840253d6604827ed4d720d40a00a5f7e8ea04ea&

Many people will not want to download a movie to see what you are describing. Consider adding a screenshot to your question.

Even watching that movie won't help. Point out your problem by adding screenshots.
